# postgres query to retrieve attributes from json array type column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

how to get the values for inputs -->r1 --> work3 atributes like a, b from following json array from postgres query

```json
[
  {
    "calculation": "Not_Applicable",
    "inputs": {
      "r1": [
        {
          "work1": [
            {
              "oid": "WEEKLY_OT_1",
              "clientFactor": 1.5,
              "threshold": "PT40H0M"
            }
          ],
          "work2": "premiumWeeklyOT",
          "work3": [
            {
              "a": "0001",
              "b": "Bi-Weekly"
            },
            {
              "a": "0002",
              "b": "Monthly"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "policy1": [
        "8639587_1"
      ],
      "policy2": [
        "8639587_1"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

expected output would be
[enter image description here][1]

```
a     b
100   hundred
200   two hundred
```

Comment: I don't see the value `100` nor "hundred" in your sample data. Where does that come from in the expected output

Answer (score 0):

By repeatedly `cross join`ing the results from `jsonb_array_elements`, you can access the values of `work3`:

```
select v2 -> 'a', v2 -> 'b' from test t 
cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.js) v 
cross join jsonb_array_elements(v -> 'inputs' -> 'r1') v1 
cross join jsonb_array_elements(v1 -> 'work3') v2
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GzlidNnx).